# Conditional Picklist for managed object

Tags: visualforce, picklist

I would like to set up conditional picklist for the managed object which is using in our system.

Example:

```
Department : Art => Major : Japanese/Spanish/etc.

Department : Science => Major : Bio/Chemistry/etc.
```

So if user selects [Art] as [Department] , then [Major] should only display picklist of [Jpananese/Spanish/etc].

As I am not how I can achieve it without writing code for managed object, I would like to know some hint or advice.

Main point is Layout out is customized Visual force page, only the standard page for mananged object.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the custom field page for Department, you should be able to create a new "Field Dependency" of the Major field. You can choose which Major fields appear according to which Departments.

It shouldn't matter that these fields are fields on a managed object - I've created field dependencies on managed objects and fields before.

Comment: perfect answer for me. here is the link I refer to create what I want. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm